# Add or Update object in array in JSON using jq

Tags: json, jq

I'm trying to use `jq` to parse a JSON (the output of the OpenShift `oc process ...` command, actually), and *add/update* the *env* array of a `container` with a new key/value pair.

**Sample input**:

```
{
  "kind": "List",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {},
  "items": [
    {
      "apiVersion": "v1",
      "kind": "Service",
      "metadata": {
        "annotations": {
          "description": "Exposes and load balances the node.js application pods"
        },
        "name": "myapp-web"
      },
      "spec": {
        "ports": [
          {
            "name": "web",
            "port": 3000,
            "protocol": "TCP",
            "targetPort": 3000
          }
        ],
        "selector": {
          "name": "myapp"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "apiVersion": "v1",
      "kind": "Route",
      "metadata": {
        "name": "myapp-web"
      },
      "spec": {
        "host": "app.internal.io",
        "port": {
          "targetPort": "web"
        },
        "to": {
          "kind": "Service",
          "name": "myapp-web"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "apiVersion": "v1",
      "kind": "DeploymentConfig",
      "metadata": {
        "annotations": {
          "description": "Defines how to deploy the application server"
        },
        "name": "myapp"
      },
      "spec": {
        "replicas": 1,
        "selector": {
          "name": "myapp"
        },
        "strategy": {
          "type": "Rolling"
        },
        "template": {
          "metadata": {
            "labels": {
              "name": "myapp"
            },
            "name": "myapp"
          },
          "spec": {
            "containers": [
              {
                "env": [
                  {
                    "name": "A_ENV",
                    "value": "a-value"
                  }
                ],
                "image": "node",
                "name": "myapp-node",
                "ports": [
                  {
                    "containerPort": 3000,
                    "name": "app",
                    "protocol": "TCP"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        "triggers": [
          {
            "type": "ConfigChange"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

In this JSON, I want to do the following:

- Find the `DeploymentConfig` object
- Check if it has the `env` array in the first container
- If it does, add a new object `{"name": "B_ENV", "value": "b-value"}` in it
- If it does not, add the `env` *array*, with the object `{"name": "B_ENV", "value": "b-value"}` in it

So far, I'm able to tackle part of this, where I'm able to find the concerned object, and add the new env var to the container:

```bash
oc process -f <dc.yaml> -o json | jq '.items | map(if .kind == "DeploymentConfig" 
    then .spec.template.spec.containers[0].env |= .+ [{"name": "B_ENV", "value": "b-value"}] 
    else . 
    end)'
```

This is able to insert the new env var as expected, but the output is an array as shown below. <s>Also, it doesn't handle the part where the `env` array may not be there at all.</s>

I want to be able to produce the same output as the input, but with the new env var added.

**Sample output**:

```
[
  {
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "kind": "Service",
    "metadata": {
      "annotations": {
        "description": "Exposes and load balances the node.js application pods"
      },
      "name": "myapp-web"
    },
    "spec": {
      "ports": [
        {
          "name": "web",
          "port": 3000,
          "protocol": "TCP",
          "targetPort": 3000
        }
      ],
      "selector": {
        "name": "myapp"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "kind": "Route",
    "metadata": {
      "name": "myapp-web"
    },
    "spec": {
      "host": "app.internal.io",
      "port": {
        "targetPort": "web"
      },
      "to": {
        "kind": "Service",
        "name": "myapp-web"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "kind": "DeploymentConfig",
    "metadata": {
      "annotations": {
        "description": "Defines how to deploy the application server"
      },
      "name": "myapp"
    },
    "spec": {
      "replicas": 1,
      "selector": {
        "name": "myapp"
      },
      "strategy": {
        "type": "Rolling"
      },
      "template": {
        "metadata": {
          "labels": {
            "name": "myapp"
          },
          "name": "myapp"
        },
        "spec": {
          "containers": [
            {
              "env": [
                {
                  "name": "A_ENV",
                  "value": "a-value"
                },
                {
                  "name": "B_ENV",
                  "value": "b-value"
                }
              ],
              "image": "node",
              "name": "myapp-node",
              "ports": [
                {
                  "containerPort": 3000,
                  "name": "app",
                  "protocol": "TCP"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "triggers": [
        {
          "type": "ConfigChange"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Is this doable, or is it too much to do with `jq`, and I should probably do this in python or node?

**EDIT 1**:

I just realized that conditional add/update of `env` array is already handled by the `|=` syntax!
So, I basically just need to be able to get the *same* structure back as the input, with the relevant env var added in the concerned array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You pretty much had it, but you'll want to restructure your filter to preserve the full results.  You want to make sure that none of the filters changes the context.  By starting off with `.items`, you changed it from your root object to the `items` array.  That in of itself is not so much a problem but what you do with that matters.  Keep in mind that assignments/updates preserves the original context as a result with the change applied.  So if you wrote your filter in terms of an update, it will work for you.

So to do this, you'll want to find the `env` array of the first container in the `DeploymentConfig` item.  First let's find that:

```
.items[] | select(.kind == "DeploymentConfig").spec.template.spec.containers[0].env
```

You don't need to do anything else in terms of error handling since `select` will simply produce no result.  From there, you just need to update the array by adding the new value.

```
(.items[] | select(.kind == "DeploymentConfig").spec.template.spec.containers[0].env) +=
    [{name:"B_ENV",value:"b-value"}]
```

If the array exists, it will add the new item. If not, it will create a new `env` array.  If `env` is not an array, that would be a different problem.

Comment: Awesome! _Keep in mind that assignments/updates preserves the original context as a result with the change applied._ was the key insight. Thanks a lot, Jeff!